# Haskell: Compare Average to List of Averages

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am trying to compare averages to each other via Haskell. I've got a list of lists of doubles and a list of doubles. What I want is to compare the average of each list of doubles (from the list of lists of doubles) to the average of the other list of doubles. When the average is higher, I want to return that list of Doubles.

I don't know how to do this in Haskell. Does anybody know how to get me started? Do I need some sort of iteration or can I do this with map? Thanks!

Edit:
I have a function to calculate the average of an array:

```
calculateAverage :: [Double] -> Double
calculateAverage xs = sum xs / fromIntegral (length xs)
```

And this is what I've tried, I know it doesn't make much sense but I don't know how to combine if or where with map:

```
listsGreaterThenAverage :: [[Double]] -> [Double] -> [[Double]]
listsGreaterThenAverage x y = map (if map calculateAverage x > calculateAverage y then x)
```

I will get a list of lists of doubles and compare the average of every list of doubles to the average of the second argument, a list of doubles. If the average of the list of doubles (from  the list of lists of doubles) is greater then the average of the second list of doubles, it will add the list of doubles to the return value.

Comment: Can you provide an example of input and desired output?

Comment: What have you tried so far? you could `map` a function that computes average over a list (a fold) to the list of list of double and then compare to the average of the other list.

Comment: I added more info in an edit of the question. Sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear exactly what you're asking, but I suggest you look at the `map` function, which applies a function to each element of a list. You should probably use a `let` expression or a `where` clause to save the average of the list you wish to compare with the rest. Think about how you can calculate the average value of a list without having to traverse it twice.

Comment: Indeed. I've made a function to calculate the average of a list of Doubles and then I wanted to use a map and if or where but I got stuck. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1):

How many lists are there in the list of lists? Give a sample of your data, please, that would greatly help. You can write a comprehension, if i'm understanding what you mean, where your return list is filled with average values of the lists inside the list of lists, provided that they're the max of averages.

Comment: I want to make the function independent from how many elements in list of lists to make it reusable. I provided more info in edit.